# Android 4.4.4 Display *content much bigger*

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

i get reports that the calendar of my App "MyDays" on Android 4.4.4 is not full visible. Instead the whole display seems zoomed 4 times, so only a part is visible.

its a relative layout with tablerows!

It was working fine with all other Firmwares before.
Any Idea what this could be (i cant test for now as i dont have 4.4.4)

i used to have

```
 <supports-screens 
 android:anyDensity="false" 
 android:normalScreens="true" 
 android:largeScreens="true" 
 android:smallScreens="true" 
 android:resizeable="true">
 </supports-screens>
```

when i made anyDensity =' true' before, THAN i had problems... but not with 'false"

thanks
chris

Comment: Hard to know without more info. Are you displaying images? Calculating view sizes (or view content sizes) in pixels? Are you correctly using density-specific resource folders?

Comment: As said, its just a TableLayout. That already looks bigger, beside Images etc.

Comment: The row and cell sizes are very likely sized to the contents, so if the images, etc., are too big, the table will appear too big. That's why I asked about the table contents; without knowing anything about that, it is unlikely that anybody will be able to help you.